# How do I regain my health?

Tags: dont-starve

The question [Reliable food source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96100/reliable-food-source) touches on it briefly, but I was hoping to get an in-depth focus on all the ways to regain health in this game or at least the ones that are easy to acquire. What are all of the methods I can use to regain health?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a complete list here http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Food

Comment: I want to say health also slowly regenerates over time but not 100%

Comment: didn't imagine that honey is just that powerful in regaining health, wow

Comment: Honey restored 6 health points when I ate some just now.

Comment: The linked information needs to be summarized here.  That saves people a click, and ensures your answer is still valid, even if the site itself goes down.

Comment: This answer only answers part of the question. It only shows foods that heal, but spider glands, mosquito sacks, healing salves, live giving amulets, ... heal too.

Answer (score 0):

JERKY is also an excellent source of health, i think it's somewhere between 8 and 15 points of health and it only costs you one morsel and a drying rack which is obviously reusable